# Rayleigh criterion for sound and parabolic microphone

Tags: acoustics, reflection, diffraction

Currently I am developing a parabolic microphone for a study project. I've heard and read that the maximum wavelength of sound that the given diameter microphone can focus is determined based on the Rayleigh criterion. However, I couldn't find any thorough explanation with sound-related formulas. Is that right? What is the formula for sound then? I know that it is also connected with diffraction limit.

Comment: There are a couple of critical differences between acoustics and optics, especially in technical applications. In optics the approximation of infinite far field and plane waves is much more useful than in acoustics, where the performance near the ground (which in case of low frequencies is within a wavelength of the floor) is of importance. So while you may use the formulas from optics as a zeroth or maybe first order approximation, the actual performance of the device may vary considerably. What's your application?

Comment: My application is a parabolic reflector focusing sound waves to a focal point. I would like to know how to calculate the minimum frequency (i.e. maximum wavelenght) that can be focused by a reflector of a given diameter. I am interested in rough approximation, very theoretical. I hope I adressed your comment appropriately.

Comment: I understand what the microphone is supposed to do. My point is that what the device will really do depends very strongly on the geometry in which it will be used in. Are you trying to record birds or is it a technical application?

Comment: Ok, so the device's geometry is:
diameter - 0,5m
depth - 0,125m
focal length - 0,125m
with the according cross-sectional parabola described by a formula y=(x^2)/50

Is this the geometry that you need?

Comment: But are you using it 1m or 10m above the ground? Is this in free space or in a closed room? Are you recording a single frequency or a whole spectrum? Can you correct for its response? Would you be better of with multiple microphones and a phase sensitive setup? As I said, in acoustics these things matter much more than in optics. What is your ultimate performance requirement?

Comment: Ok, so there are no precise settings determined. It will be used on varying height, environment, whole spectrum of frequencies. Is there a way to determine the theoretical wavelenght limit then?

Comment: In that case using the free space wavelength limit will simply not make any sense because you will see local interference at low frequencies cause significant distortions in the response. That's what I meant in my first post. Optics differs from acoustics because we can neglect those effects. As for the theoretical performance of a 0.5m device, there are plenty of frequency plots on the internet. You don't have to calculate anything because people have measured it for you, already.

Comment: Can you provide some examples? I only have found this one and this is not exactly the thing that I need. http://www.coe.montana.edu/ee/rmaher/publications/maher_aac_0805.pdf

Comment: What's wrong with that? That paper is about as good as one can do acoustics with passive setups like a parabolic microphone. If you need better than that, especially at low frequencies, I would strongly suggest to go to a phased array of multiple microphones. Gain and directivity are, after all, used to gain SNR, so it may be better to explore other ways to achieve the SNR requirement than exclusively with reflecting surfaces.